# Filters and conditions in window functions in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements, window-functions

I have a sample dataset like below

```
 Name   date        Category    transactionamount
Adam    1/1/2020    Mobile      100
Adam    1/1/2020    Tab         200
Bob     1/1/2020    Mobile      200
Adam    2/1/2020    Tab         200
Bob     2/1/2020    Mobile      200
Adam    3/1/2020    Tab         200
Bob     4/1/2020    Mobile      200
```

I want to sum transactionamount column over a rolling period of current and previous day , so my code for window frame looks like below

```
val windowspec = Window.partitionBy($"name").orderBy($"date".asc)

val range = windowspec.rangeBetween(-1, 0)

val aasum2 = sum('transactionAmount).over(range)

df.select('date,'name,aasum2 as 'aasum).orderBy('date,'name).show(100,false)
```

This works fine for general summation without condition.

But I want output like below table with two new columns based on category column value.

Every output row should contain summation value for distinct date and name.

How we can apply condition(based on value of other column) while doing window function over a column

```
date        Name    Mobile_sum  Tab_sum
1/1/2020    Adam    100         200
1/1/2020    Bob     200         0
2/1/2020    Adam    0           400
2/1/2020    Bob     400         0
3/1/2020    Adam    0           600
3/1/2020    Bob     0           0
4/1/2020    Adam    0           0
4/1/2020    Bob     200         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your additional column to your `partitionBy()` within your `WindowSpec`